# Proof of exponential complex constant holomorphic

Tags: complex-analysis

If we let

$ g(z) = e^{f(z)} $

and $f$ is holomorphic on a region G, how do we prove that $f$ is a constant if $g$ is a constant?

Do we just simply find the derivative of $g(z)$ and set it to zero, hence, a constant?
i.e. $g'(z) = e^{f(z)} f'(z) = 0 $

$-> $ $f'(z) = 0$ implies $f(z)=constant$ ?

Comment: I don't really understand your questions. Your line of reasoning is fine. $f$ is analytic hence $g$ is analytic since $\exp$ is entire. Furthermore, $\exp(y) \neq 0$ for all $y$.

Comment: edit: basically it's just proving that $g$ is also a constant if $f$ is a constant. all i know though is that the functions are constants iff their derivatives are $0$. is this right?

Comment: If the derivative is zero then the function is constant on the connected components. Since $G$ is a region, it is connected, so the answer is yes.

Comment: so from what I understand from you, it is sufficient through simply this derivative?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}{}$